# Parsing text from HTML using jQuery: search between elements and content

Tags: jquery, parsing, groovy

OK, so, looks like I didn't write this clearly. I'm a java and selenium guy, so I'm totally new to Groovy and jQuery, so pardon my ignorance in this matter. I'm going to attempt to rewrite this.

I'm doing test automation on a page on the browser.

My main objective is to parse through an HTML page, and match a specific criteria (see below). Once that area/section is found, I need to extract texts from that section only, and print them to a console.

The HTML is as follows:

```
<div class="lines"></div>
<div class="next"></div>

<h2>Company1</h2>
<p>CompanyXYZ is awesome</p>
<p>CompanyXYZ is great.</p>
<p>I'm don't talking about CompanyXYZ.
  <br>
<a name="hiddenTag"></a>
</p>
<div class="lines"></div>
```

Within this page, I need to search for the section between `<h2>Company1</h2>` (since there are other headers with Company2, Company3 etc) and `<a name="hiddenTag"></a>`.  From that section of text, I need to  then parse out the last word of each sentence (i.e. before the '.' (period)) within each `<p>`... `</p>` sections, which in this case are "awesome" and "great".

I know how to do this using java and selenium (identify the two HTML elements, and extract the string between those two elements), but I'm totally new at both groovy and jQuery.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm confused, are you trying to do this in the browser (jQuery) or not (Groovy)?

Comment: Yes, trying to do this via code, in Groovy. But i'm using Geb's (automation tool) Browser to drive it. So, to select items in Geb, I need to use jQuery to identify objects/elements? Does that make sense?

Comment: `parse those words` doesn't tell anyone what you want to do with them. Overall issue explanation is not very clear

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. I mean that I need to parse the last words from each of the "<p>" tags. In this case, the words "awesome" and "great". I simply need to either save them to a string, or print them out to a console. Thanks.

Comment: your whole question needs a rewrite. Make up your mind where you want this done and be more specific about what needs to be done. Is objective to look for specific words or last works or ??? You should also show some sort of attempt to resolve this yourself

Comment: Ok attempting rewrite.

Comment: Rewrote question with better wordings.

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to parse html in groovy, but it needs to be well formed. I have no idea how to do that "slice" gracefully, so i'm going for the old flag-fashioned way:

```
text='''<html><div class="lines"></div>
<div class="next"></div>

<h2>Company1</h2>
<p>CompanyXYZ is awesome</p>
<p>CompanyXYZ is great.</p>
<p>I'm don't talking about CompanyXYZ.
  <br/>
<a name="hiddenTag"></a>
</p>
<div class="lines"></div></html>'''

html = new XmlSlurper().parseText text
elemsBetween = []
company1Found = false

html.breadthFirst().each {
  if (company1Found) {
    elemsBetween << it
  }
  if (it.text() == "Company1") {
    company1Found = true
  }
  if (it.@name.text() == "hiddenTag") {
    company1Found = false
  }
}

comments = elemsBetween.findResults { it.text() ?: null }*.trim()

assert comments == [
  'CompanyXYZ is awesome',
  'CompanyXYZ is great.',
  """I'm don't talking about CompanyXYZ."""      ]
```

If your html is not well formed, groovy will cough on `XmlSlurper::parseText`, upon which you are better using some HTML cleaner, like [neko](http://nekohtml.sourceforge.net/), which is [brain-dead to use](https://gist.github.com/lyhcode/4387321) (though note all tag's names get uppercased)